# Admob ads implementation gives errors

Tags: java, android, admob, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

It gives these errors when I try to run the app. Can anybody help me please?

[image]

Comment: To help others help you better, please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file is limited. That's why you should enable Multidex.
Make the following changes in your module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
    android {
        ....
    
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    
    dependencies {
        ...
        implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1" // if you're using AndroidX
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // or add this one if you don't use AndroidX
    }
```

You might also need to change your application class file:

1. If you don't use your own Application class, add the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.yourapp">
        <application
                ...
                android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

2. If you override the `Application` class, make sure your class extends `MultiDexApplication`:

```java
    public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
        // your app code
    }
```

More details about Multidex you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex).